# Is there a way to use a Custom cross-sectional slicer of 3d image data?

Tags: xtk

I mean, is there a way to use the current slicer to show a sectional slice (not aligned with the canonical Axis) of the 3D image data?  or better, a sectional slice of a predefined size.

If there is no exists, how can I contribute with this ??

Regards,
P

Comment: Hi, is there a solution for this problem already? Would be very nice to have this functinoality.

Answer (score 0):

currently this is not possible but you are very welcome to contribute.

the parsers of NRRD and MGH/MGZ format store a 3D array of the image. All X.slices are configured using a front and an up vector.. now we only have to link the X.slice to grab the right values from the 3D array and then create a widget so it is possible to reslice/reformat on the fly. Sounds good?

Comment: Hi, is there a solution for this problem already? Would be very nice to have this functinoality.